# UINavigationBar hide the view button after showing it

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I am now using UINavigationController in my application .I have added a button to the view of this navigationcontroller so that this button appears on top of the navigationBar .
The problem is when I hide the navigationBar and also hide the button and show them again ,the NavigationBar appears on top of the button .
Can anyone solve this issue ?

```
@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController<UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{

    UIButton *btnBack ;  
}
-(id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    self = [super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    if (self)
    {
        self.delegate = self ;


        self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;


        //btnBack
        UIImageView *gameImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 32, 27)];
        self.btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5.0, 60, 30);
        [self.btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backicon.png"]  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.btnBack addSubview: gameImage];
        [self.view addSubview:self.btnBack];

    }
    return self ;
}
-(void)hideNavigationItems
{
    [self setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    self.btnBack.hidden = YES ;

}
-(void)showNavigationItems
{
    self.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    self.btnBack.hidden = NO ;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried:

- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comment, try:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnBack];
```

Comment: No problem SamehDos. It might make sense to put your code in your question rather than in the answers section, but otherwise glad I could help :)